# Modules over commutative absolutely flat rings vs. vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, soft-question, modules

The theory of commutative absolutely flat rings (a.k.a. commutative von Neumann regular rings) is algebraic and furthermore it is the smallest variety containing all fields. Being a variety the category of (set-theoretic) models is arguably much better behaved than the category of fields.

> How does linear algebra in modules over commutative absolutely flat rings compare
>   to plain linear algebra, i.e. working with vector spaces? Is is it
>   basically the same or are there some major differences?

Let's ask some more concrete questions:

Let $R$ be an commutative absolutely flat ring: Are finitely generated $R$-modules always free? Assuming the axiom of choice: Are *all* $R$-modules free?

Comment: The smallest variety containing all fields is the variety of all commutative rings. To see this it is enough to note that any free commutative ring is a domain, hence is embeddable in a field.

Comment: @KeithKearnes Huh. I may have a serious misconception. I was basing that on this http://mathoverflow.net/a/91969/78650.

Comment: In that mathoverflow question they were expanding the language of rings to include a multiplicative inverse operation as a new fundamental operation. The objects obtained were no longer just rings, but rather objects they referred to as *inverse rings*. Analogously, the class of semigroups that are embeddable in groups is not a variety, but becomes one if you add the inverse as a new operation.

Comment: Let me correct my previous comment. Where I say "the class of semigroups embeddable in groups" I should have said "the class of all reducts of groups to the language of semigroups".

Comment: @KeithKearnes Yes, I didn't mean "variety with the same language", I meant variety in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OP]

"Let's ask some more concrete questions:

Let *R*
be an commutative absolutely flat ring: Are finitely generated *R*-modules always free? Assuming the axiom of choice: Are all *R*-modules free?"

[Answer]

Not necessarily.

Every nontrivial (unital) ring has a simple module, which is finitely generated, in fact 1-generated. *R* has a **free** simple left module iff *R* has no proper nontrivial left ideals iff *R* is a division ring. [The least obvious part of this claim is that if *R* has a free simple left module, then it has no proper nontrivial left ideals. You see this by observing that the only free module that could possibly be simple is the rank 1 free module, ${}_R R$. Then notice that this module is simple iff $R$ has no proper nontrivial left ideals.]

In the commutative case this shows that all (f.g.) $R$-modules are free iff $R$ is a field.

Answer (score 1):

No. Simple example: let $k$ be field. The ring $R=k\times k$ is absolutely flat, and the first factor $k$, as an $R$-module, is the cyclic $R$-module generated by the idempotent $e=(1,0)$. It's not free, since $e$ is killed by the orthogonal idempotent $1-e=(0,1)$.

Actually one proves a commutative ring $R$ is absolutely flat if and only if its Krull dimension is $0$, and its localisations at maximal ideals are fields.